# Python - I want to increase the Row-Index automatically

Tags: python, pandas

I am absolutely new to Python or coding for that matter, hence, any help would be greatly appreciated. I have around 21 Salesforce orgs and am trying to get some information from each of the org into one place to send out in an email.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("secretCSV.csv", usecols = ['client','uname','passw','stoken'])
username = df.loc[[1],'uname'].values[0]
password = df.loc[[1],'passw'].values[0]
sectocken = df.loc[[1],'stoken'].values[0]
```

I have saved all my username, password, security tokens in secretCSV.csv file and with the above code I can get the data for 1 row as the index value I have given is 0. I would like to know how can I loop through this and after each loop, how to increase the index value until all rows from the CSV file is read.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you all can offer. 
Adil

--

Comment: Look about for loops and the `range()` buildi-in function. However, I think pandas has build-in iterators, just by typing in google pandas iterrows I get decent results.

Comment: I would suggest you stop this approach. It looks like you're going to move on to iterating the dataframe and this really should be avoided, if possible. Please show and example input and expected output and we can try and come up with something better. You also wouldn't regret taking a step back and doing some pandas tutorials/exercises

Comment: Now about that "secret" csv and emailing credentials...

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate on the dataframe but it's highly not recommend (not efficient, looks bad, too much code etc)

```
df = pd.read_csv("secretCSV.csv", usecols = ['client','uname','passw','stoken'])
```

so **DO NOT DO THIS EVEN IF IT WORKS**:

```
for i in range (0, df.shape[0]):
    username = df.loc[[i],'uname'].values[0]
    password = df.loc[[i],'passw'].values[0]
    sectocken = df.loc[[i],'stoken'].values[0]
```

**Instead, do this:**

```
sec_list = [(u,p,s) for _,u,p,s in df.values]
```

now you have a sec_list with tuples (username, password, sectocken) 
access example: `sec_list[0][1]` - as in row=0 and get the password (located at [1]).

Comment: I actually wanted each of the values (username, password and security token) in separate variable so I can use it in another function as the username, password and security token to login to Salesforce.

Thank you,
Adil

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is great when you want to apply operations to a large set of data, but is usually not a good fit when you want to manipulate individual cells in python. Each cell would need to be converted to a python object each time its touched.

For your goals, I think the standard `csv` module is what you want

```
import csv

with open("secretCSV.csv", newline='') as f:
    for username, password, sectoken in csv.reader(f):
        # do all the things
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your responses. I think I will first start with python learning and then get back to this. I should have learnt coding before coding. :)

Also, I was able to iterate (sorry, most of you said not to iterate the dataframe) and get the credentials from the file.

I actually have 21 salesforce orgs and am trying to get License information from each of them and email to certain people on a daily basis. I didn't want to expose salesforce credentials, hence, went with a flat file option.

I have build the code to get the salesforce license details and able to pull the same in the format I want for 1 client. However, I have to do this for 21 clients and thought of iterating the credentials so I can run the getLicense function on loop until all 21 client's data is fetched.

I will learn Python or at least learn a little bit more than what I know now and come back to this again. Until then, Informatica and batch script would have to do.

Thank you again to each one of you for your help!

Adil

--